# WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT in oracle forms 12C not opening .csv file

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

I'm generating a CSV file using Oracle 12c AS on windows server. I need to display this file to the user using WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT. The CSV file is getting generated in the specified directory. The application URL is: "http://10.92.1.12:9001/forms/frmservlet?.

I'm passing the parameters as follows:

```
vc_path := 'Sheets/overdue_stmt_' || time2 || '.csv'; 
web.show_document('/forms/home/' || vc_path);
```

So, what I need to use in order to display this CSV file? I'm totally blank on this one.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

[Please see the image for better understanding which is showing Error 404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvF3q.jpg)

Comment: @APC I'm passing the parameters as follows,      
vc_path := 'Sheets/overdue_stmt_' || time2 || '.csv';
        web.show_document('/forms/home/' || vc_path);

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to include additional details or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In forms 12 the security has become more advanced to access files.
In the httpd.conf you have to add something like this:

```
<Directory "yourdirectory">
 Options Indexes MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in 11g, adding alias in ohs was enough, in 12c, we need to modify httpd.conf file too.
check below blogpost for detailed configuration.

https://oraclescribble.blogspot.com/2022/08/create-alias-in-oracle-12c-ohs-open.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32478857)